# How do I delete imap email accounts without opening Mail

Tags: mail.app, macos

After Yosemite update Mail crashes as soon as I open with an 'Absolute path' error. I've tried all the usual things

- removing the Envelop Index (hangs without crashing)
- turning off all the mail accounts in System Preferences

The error message indicates its an issue with some IMAP account but I still have a POP account that I need to keep, so I can't just delete the ~/Library/Mail folder. Is there a way to delete the IMAP accounts by editing the plist files.

---

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Absolute path passed into -[MFIMAPAccount mailboxForRelativePath:isFilesystemPath:create:]: //Archive'
abort() called

Comment: If you can't delete it, why not just move ~/Library/Mail instead then?

Comment: I can't delete it because it would mean losing my POP mail. Of course I can delete it, I don't want to delete it!

Comment: Hence why I recommend moving it.

Comment: But then how do I get the pop emails back into mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Internet Accounts -> Delete / Disable your email.

Comment: This is what I mentioned in the original question but you stating to actually *delete* the accounts (just the IMAP ones) actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the rules worked for me. 
Imap accounts did crash mail with me too.
Tried every solution I could find.
At last removing rules did the trick for me.